# Table design help: Need multiple different entities pointing to an an entity grouping

Tags: database, database-design, denormalization

I can't for the life of me get this through my head.  It seemed so simple at first and now I've stared at it for too long, I can't see the forest for the trees.

In essence we have Day divisions, these are abitrary...

```
ID  Name    Start  End
1   Name1   1300   1400
2   Name2   13:30  19:30
3   Name3   20:00  21:30
```

etc

We want to be able to configure the days of a week with any combination of these day divisions, so we have the WeekConfigurations table

```
ID  ConfigurationID  DayOfWeek   DayDivisionID   Order
1   1                1           1               1
2   1                1           2               2
3   1                2           2               1
4   1                2           3               2
5   2                1           1               1
6   2                3           2               1
7   2                3           3               1
```

Now we want other entities (Person, Office etc) to have a certain week configuration assigned to them.  And this is where I'm coming un-stuck.  The configurationID I want to assign isn't the primary key so I can't enforce the referential integrity between the entities and a configuration.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Something about the WeekConfiguration table smells funny to me, but I just can't see it.

PS: Sorry, I had a nice diagram to illustrate but I'm a newbie and can't add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the logical level, you have a "configuration" and a set of "configuration items" under that configuration. So instead of just one configuration table, use two:

[image]

In this design, the `ConfigurationId` is a primary key (of `Configuration` table), so you can directly use it as a parent endpoint of foreign keys.

The `ConfigurationItem` PK ensures a single day division can be used in at most one day of week per configuration and the alternate key `U1` ensures it is unambiguously ordered (within the same day of week and configuration).

I have also chosen to avoid a surrogate PK in `ConfigurationItem`. You can easily add it (and make the existing PK alternate) if necessary - e.g. if you have additional FKs you didn't mention or use an ORM that doesn't play well with composite PKs.

Comment: Ahh, there it is, of course.  Thanks for going the extra mile and giving me a diagram!

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  `WeekConfiguration` should be split into two tables.

To enforce referential integrity you need a table in which there is exactly one record (and one ID) per week configuration; this table should have the column that you call `ConfigurationID` and maybe some kind of description.

The other table (we might call it `` `WeekConfigurationDetail ``) should store detail records, day divisions that the week configurations are composed of.  While the columns would be similar to your existing table, its primary key (`ConfigurationID` again) would itself be a foreign key to the main `WeekConfiguration` table.  In the same way, any other table (entities) would be able to foreign reference that one.

Even if you had only one column in the `WeekConfiguration` table, a meaningless ID, you still need the table to ensure referential integrity.

This database design pattern is called master-detail, or also parent-child.

Comment: Thanks Jirka, I knew there was something wrong there.  I'll hack away at it